# How to check when self.close(); executed or not in java?

Tags: selenium2, java, javascript

the code is **self.close();** some times the window is closed and sometime it doesn't closed and not throwing any popup or alert. So i wanted to check whether the window is closed or still open? How it can be done through **selenium**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly... You should store the ID (of the window you're trying to close) in a variable.

After calling the close method, check if the window ID still exists.
If it does, something went wrong.

Example in C#. Instead of the String.Equals check, you can also get a list of all windowHandles and check if the specific handle is still in it.
**Edit**: didn't test this, just an idea to get you going.

```
string handle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
driver.Close();
if (String.Equals(handle, driver.CurrentWindowHandle))
    throw new Exception("Not closed!");
```